# How do i sort the numeric values within a cell in Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, series

I have a panda series/column where values are like -

| Values |
| --- |
| 101;1001 |
| 130;125 |
| 113;99 |
| 1001;101 |

I need to sort the values within the cell with an expected outcome like below using python as the dataframe is large with more than 5 million values so any faster way would be appreciated.

| Values |
| --- |
| 101;1001 |
| 125;130 |
| 99;113 |
| 101;1001 |

Comment: Al the values 101;1001 supposed to be in two different columns?

Comment: can you create few lines of the columns so it can be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Convert splitted values to integers, sorting, convert back to strings and join:

```
df['Values'] = df['Values'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(';'))))))
```

**Performance**:

```
#10k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

#enke solution
In [52]: %timeit df['Values'].str.split(';').explode().sort_values(key=lambda x: x.str.zfill(10)).groupby(level=0).agg(';'.join)
616 ms ± 6.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [53]: %timeit df['Values'].apply(lambda x: ';'.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(';'))))))
70.7 ms ± 420 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
#1M rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000000, ignore_index=True)

#mozway solution
In [60]: %timeit df['Values'] = [';'.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(';'))))) for x in df['Values']]
8.03 s ± 409 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [61]: %timeit df['Values'] = df['Values'].map(lambda x: ';'.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(';'))))))
7.88 s ± 602 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Solution for 2 columns:

```
df1 = df['Values'].str.split(';', expand=True).astype(int)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df1, axis=1), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df1)
     0     1
0  101  1001
1  125   130
2   99   113
3  101  1001
```

Comment: `8.03 s ± 409 ms` vs `7.88 s ± 602 ms` is not statistically significant ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, this will be faster on small datasets:

```
df['Values'] = [';'.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split(';'))))) for x in df['Values']]
```

output:

```
     Values
0  101;1001
1   125;130
2    99;113
3  101;1001
```

timings:

[image: timings]

For two columns:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([sorted(map(int, x.split(';'))) for x in df['Values']])
```

output:

```
     0     1
0  101  1001
1  125   130
2   99   113
3  101  1001
```

Comment: hmmm, OP has 5 millions rows `dataframe is large with more than 5 million values`

Comment: @jezrael the list comprehension and apply converge, so there is no reason not to use the list comprehension that is always "fast", no? That said the `apply` is also a valid solution. NB. I don't see a significant difference on 5M rows